# How to create regex for this year and the previous year?

Tags: java, regex, java-8

I am creating regular expression for last six months values using **Java** and **MongoDB**, 
I am able to create a regex for current year and current month using below snippet,

```
StringBuilder regexPattern = new StringBuilder("id");
regexPattern.append(":");       
regexPattern.append(today.getYear());

if(today.getMonthValue()>9)
    regexPattern.append(today.getMonthValue());
 else
             regexPattern.append("0").append(today.getMonthValue());

        regexPattern.append(".*");
```

This above snippet gives me the output as : **id:201703.***
Likewise I need to generate values for both from November 10th 2016 to Mar 2nd 2017.

Please help me out .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe _getLastYear()_ ?

Comment: the  getLatYear() will help me to get a lastyear values , but required  is I need to have regex which includes the condition from Nov 10th 2016 to 2nd Mar 2017..

Comment: If today is 2nd Mar 2017, set today for Nov 10th 2016. Or, use a date/time module to get today _and_ today - 6 months.

Comment: this is how my data stored in db : "id:20160613","tenantId" : 2,"subTenantId" : "21", "_id" : "id:20170302", "tenantId" : 2,"subTenantId" : "22",

Comment: You're going to have to use a date/time module for this to dynamically generate it.

Comment: yes , need to use both date and time

Comment: Regex doesn't "recognize" dates or numbers as anything more than groups that fit within characters the engine defines as digits. For instance, there's no syntax to say `(\d{1,2}) \d(greater than $1)`

Comment: You could maintain a static list of months and days, and based on _todays_ values, construct a regex using the lists.

Comment: Do you really need Java code that generates monstrous regexes like this: `id:201(70(2(2([0-8])|0([1-9])|1(\d))|1(3([0-1])|0([1-9])|[1-2](\d))|301)|61(2(3([0-1])|0([1-9])|[1-2](\d))|1([1-2](\d)|30)))`? If yes, may I ask what you are going to do with that? Validate the IDs? Select documents from MongoDB?

Comment: Yes Markus, I need java code , because our application is running multiple databases with multiple Geo regions. If possible please provide me the code sample . Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use this to generate the patterns. It collects all the patterns into a single `List`.

You can iterate through this list and generate a Regular Expression pattern as per your need.

```
public class DateRegEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate _6MonthsAgo = today.minus(6, ChronoUnit.MONTHS);

        LocalDate start = _6MonthsAgo.minusDays(1);
        LocalDate end = today.minusDays(1);

        List<String> regexPattern = Stream.iterate(start, date -> date.plusMonths(1))
            .limit(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start, end.plusMonths(1)))
            .map(DateRegEx::makePattern)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(regexPattern);
    }

    private static String makePattern(LocalDate someDate) {
        StringBuilder regexPattern = new StringBuilder("id");
        regexPattern.append(":");

        regexPattern.append(someDate.getYear());

        if (someDate.getMonthValue() > 9)
            regexPattern.append(someDate.getMonthValue());
        else
            regexPattern.append("0").append(someDate.getMonthValue());

        regexPattern.append(".*");
        return regexPattern.toString();
    }

}
```

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved in this way. it gives a regex for individual months from start to end .

```
    while (!startDate.isAfter(endDate)) {

        StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder().append("reqId");
        pattern.append(":");

        LocalDate endOfMonth = startDate.withDayOfMonth(startDate.lengthOfMonth());

        LocalDate stDate = null;
        LocalDate eDate = null;

        if(actualStartDate.getMonthValue() == startDate.getMonthValue()){
            stDate=actualStartDate;
        }else{
            stDate =  startDate;
        }

        if(endOfMonth.getMonthValue() != endDate.getMonthValue()){
            eDate  =  endOfMonth ;
        }else{
            eDate  = endDate  ;
        }
        pattern.append(startDate.getYear());
        int monthValue = stDate.getMonthValue();

        if(monthValue>9)
             pattern.append(monthValue);
         else
             pattern.append("0").append(monthValue);


        if(actualStartDate.getMonthValue()!=startDate.getMonthValue() && startDate.getMonthValue() != endDate.getMonthValue()){
        }else{

            if(startDate.getDayOfMonth() == stDate.getDayOfMonth() && endOfMonth.getDayOfMonth() == eDate.getDayOfMonth()){

        }else{  
            pattern.append("(");
            int x = stDate.getDayOfMonth();
            for(int i = stDate.getDayOfMonth(); i < eDate.getDayOfMonth(); i++){

                 if(x>9)
                     pattern.append(x);
                 else
                     pattern.append("0").append(x);

                pattern.append("|");
                x++;
            }
            if(eDate.getDayOfMonth()>9)
             pattern.append(eDate.getDayOfMonth());
                else
             pattern.append("0").append(eDate.getDayOfMonth());

            pattern.append(")");

        }
        }
        pattern.append(".*");   

        System.out.println(pattern.toString());
        regexList.add(pattern.toString());
        startDate = startDate.plusMonths(1);


    String regexPattern = org.springframework.util.StringUtils.collectionToDelimitedString(regexList,"|");
```